# Spaces of continuous functions

Tags: metric-spaces, complete-spaces

I have currently been studying space of continuous functions from J.B. Conway's textbook of complex variable. In [Chapter VII](https://books.google.com/books?id=cHfdBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA138) of the textbook, it uses the notation $C(G,S)$ to denote the space of all continuous functions from open set $G$ to $S$
**WHERE $(S,d)$ is a complete metric space**.

Why is it taking the space $(S,d)$ to be complete metric space. What would happen if we take any arbitrary metric space? or is it necessary to take $(S,d)$ complete?

Comment: it's nice to have cauchy convergence of continuous functions, making $C(G,S)$ a Banach Space

Comment: It is good to be careful in technical details; but I would say it is a pity if you are stopped by this issue. Keep going on, and then you may find out a suitable "why". When you were learning differential calculus, you might not notice that most authors define differentiability of maps only on open sets, right? Overcoming such insecurity is not easy, but...

Comment: @AnthonyPeter since $S$ is just a complete metric space, $C(G, S)$ will be complete metric only. Not Banach

Comment: @user251257 Moreover, it may be some trouble to define a metric on the whole $C$ since $G$ is not compact.

Comment: @A.G. Oh right, we need $G$ sigma compact at least